# Spring xd Gemfire sink key-class and value-class parameters

Tags: spring-xd

Is there any way to use ***key-class*** and ***value-class*** parameters for the **Gemfire sink** in ***Spring xd***?
Regarding to documentation i can use only ***keyExpression*** but nothing about its class type. Same for the key-class.

I have such command for the Gemfire,

```js
put --key-class = java.lang.String --value-class = Employee --key = ('id': '998') --value = ('id': 186, 'firstName': 'James', 'lastName': 'Goslinga') --region = replicated2
```

So i use ***--key-class*** and ***--value-class*** parameters in Gemfire. 
But i cannot use them from Spring xd since there is only ***keyExpression*** parameter in ***Gemfire Sink***.

Any idea to solve?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the syntax above is not supported by native GemFire. So you can't do it out of the box with Spring XD. The syntax looks vaguely SQL-like. Are you using Gemfire XD? Is this something you wrote yourself?

The gemfire sink uses [spring-integration-gemfire](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gemfire.html), allowing you to declare the keyExpression using SpEL. The value, using the gemfire sink, is always the payload. The SI gemfire outbound adapter wraps Region.put(key, value). The GemFire API supports typing via generics, i.e. Region`<K,V>` but this is not enforced in this case. GemFire RegionFactory allows keyConstraint and valueConstraint attributes to constrain types but this is part of the Region configuration which is external to Spring XD. Furthermore, none of this addresses the data binding in your example, e.g.,

```
Person p = ('id': 186, 'firstName': 'James', 'lastName': 'Goslinga')
```

This capability would require a custom sink module. If your  command can be executed as a shell script, you might be able to use a `shell` sink to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer,

Maybe basically i can explain my problem in this way.

if i write following command to gemfire console i can create new entry in region which contains object of Employee class.

```js
put --key-class=java.lang.String --value-class=Employee --key=('id':'998') --value=('id':186,'firstName':'James','lastName':'Goslinga') --region=replicated2
```

The think that i want to do is i will send data from spring-xd. And i will have a new object of Employee class in Gemfire.

If i create such stream which will get data from rabbit MQ and send it to gemfire.

```js
stream create --name reference-data-import --definition "rabbit --outputType=text/plain | gemfire-json-server --host=MC0WJ1BC --regionName=region10 --keyExpression=payload.getField('id')" --deploy
```

I can see that data in this type of "com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.internal.PdxInstanceImpl".

Regarding to spring-xd documentation i can use such parametter outputType=application/x-java-object;type=com.bar.Foo but i never managed to work it out even though i deploy my class. 
if i can see a simple working example it will be great for me.